# Java how to jump back to While loop

Tags: java

So if `LARGE` is not equal to `Count`, then `LARGE` should increment until `Count` and `LARGE` have the same value. The thing is after that my prof wants to input a new integer again, then it will loop again, but I don't know how to make my code go back to `while`.

```
if (LARGE == Count)
{
    System.out.println ("Large is Equal to Count");
}

while (Count != LARGE)
{
    LARGE++;
    System.out.println ("Large is " +LARGE);
}

if (LARGE == Count)
{
    System.out.println ("Input a new integer to compare")
    LARGE = input.newInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding this is what you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int LARGE = 0;
        int Count = 0;
        String s = null;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {

            LARGE = sc.nextInt();
            Count = sc.nextInt();

            if (LARGE == Count) {
                System.out.println("Large is Equal to Count");
            } else {
                do {
                    LARGE++;
                    System.out.println("Large is " + LARGE);
                } while (Count != LARGE);

                if (LARGE == Count) {
                    System.out.println("Large is Equal to Count");
                    System.out.println("Input a new integer to compare");
                }

            }

            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? If yes then Press Y");
            s = sc.next();
        } while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

    }
```

Comment: Thankyousomuch im just a first yr student taking CS But the problem now is when large is not equal to Count it will infinite loop anyway in the code u  write else do is that the same as else if?

Comment: im just new here uhm where is the accept button im sorry hahah

Comment: Accepted sir Thankyou :) let me fix the infinite loop when the Large is not equal to count thankyousir thankyousomuch

Comment: if you have time will you explain me the use of String S = Null and this while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

Comment: check out string comparison operations on google, you will see many results related to it.

Answer (score 0):

How many times prof want to enter new integer, forever?
I am assuming it 1000 times.
if forever, replace 'times' to true in while braces else assign something meaningful to 'times' instead of 1000.

```
System.out.println ("Input a new integer to compare")
LARGE = input.newInt();
int times = 1000; // number of times prof want to enter new integer.
int loop = 0;
while(times > loop ){
    while (Count != LARGE)
    {
        LARGE++;
        System.out.println ("Large is " +LARGE);
    }
    System.out.println ("Input a new integer to compare")
    LARGE = input.newInt();
    loop++;
}
```

Comment: while (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) help i need explanation for  this the answer that i accepted is correct but this is the code i cant explain thankyou someone help